# Finding Length of words input by user in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new in learning Python. And I thought of writing a code.

I want the user to input some words, and I want the program to give the length of the words as output.

```
words = [raw_input("Enter a name: ")]

def len_name(words):
    for x in words:
        print(x, len(x))

len_name(words)
```

Now, when the user gives a single word as input, say aeroplane, the program gives the following output and that's correct.

```
Enter a name: aeroplane
('aeroplane', 9)
```

But if user give two words as output, it give the following:

```
Enter a name: aeroplane, fish
('aeroplane, fish', 15)
```

I was looking for the code to give different words and their length.

What did I mess up?

Comment: You're looking for the `split` method.  Work through a tutorial on string handling, and you'll have the techniques.

Comment: split the input into a list of words, and return a list of lengths?

Comment: Use `for x in words[0].split(','):  print(x.strip(), len(x.strip()))`. I tried it and it's working for your example. It will not count the spaces for the length and assumes that your words are separated by comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix to your current code would be to not create a list for the multiple words since they are all one entry, and then `.split(', ')` that entry when its passed to `len_name()` and then do as you were with `for i in x`. Also functions should return a value not just print. A revised version would be:

```
def len_name(x):
    lista = []
    for i in x.split(', '):
        lista.append((i, len(i)))
    return lista

words = input('Enter a name: ')
word_len = len_name(words)
for i in word_len:
    print(*i)
```

> ```
> Enter a name: vash, the, stampede
> vash 4
> the 3
> stampede 8
> ```

Or using *list comprehension* and a loop to print

```
word_len = [(i, len(i)) for i in input('Enter a name: ').split(', ')]
for i in word_len:
    print(i[0], i[1])
```

Comment: The OP's input is comma separated. Look at the example he/she provided

Comment: @Bazingaa fixed , ty

Comment: Also, you could simply write `for i in x.split(', ')` and remove `x = x.split(', ')`. Check my comment to the above answer from schwobaseggl

Comment: @Bazingaa yeah I am aware I skipped over that I dont know why I'm used to getting an error when I try to use comprehension with `[i for i in x.split()` so I just added the extra step here but it does indeed work that way updating again

Comment: `[i for i in i.split()` should be `[i for i in x.split()` or whatever you are trying to do

Comment: @Bazingaa was generally speaking, meant x

Comment: Your list comprehension also prints `[None, None, None]`

Comment: @Bazingaa is that only when using the python console? I know this can happen but if I run the code, it does'nt print the `[None, None, None]`

Comment: @Bazingaa what I mean is if i write this comprehension in a `.py` and run it it doesn't print the `None`s but I'm aware that happens when running the terminal python console, does this mean this method should be avoided all together

Comment: I ran it in JuPyter Notebook.

Answer (score 2):

`words = [raw_input("Enter a name: ")]` takes the input and puts it in a `list` as a **single** element: `['aeroplane, fish']`. In order to obtain `['aeroplane', 'fish']`, you need to [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the input with an appropriate delimiter:

```
words = raw_input("Enter a name: ").split(', ')
# or a little more robustly wrt white space:
words = [w.strip() for w in raw_input("Enter a name: ").split(',')]
```

Comment: What if user enter the words without a space after the comma? You would need `strip()` too

Comment: Well, I said "appropriate delimiter", and you can only work with the sample input the OP provides. This question seems to ask for basic functions, not heavy NLP :)

Comment: Still a slight general solution taking care of spaces would be nice because the requirement here is to count length of words ignoring spaces and commas. But anyway

Comment: @Bazingaa Ok, convinced.

Answer (score 0):

You are current reading in a line, so it doesn't care about what is there in terms of spaces, or common separated words etc.

So you need to split the read in line into words using split